# Trouble with geom_ribbon

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have tried working from examples and previous forum questions, but have not had any success.  I am plotting a set of mean temperatures at specific times, and use `geom_ribbon` to show standard error.  However, standard error keeps showing up as lines rather than a ribbon, and I really want the ribbon!

Sample of data (I have ~2900 observations):

```
     time   tank mean.temp  SE.temp
2494 2047    4  11.85682 0.04130505
2495 2048    3  11.46500 0.04811178
2496 2048    4  11.90000 0.04215452
2497 2049    3  11.50244 0.04907533
2498 2049    4  11.86512 0.03893427
2499 2050    3  11.48000 0.05149855
2500 2050    4  11.92857 0.04251968
```

Here is my code:

```
p<-ggplot(temp.data, aes(x=time, y=mean.temp, group=tank))
p+ geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=mean.temp-SE.temp, ymax=mean.temp+SE.temp, fill="gray"), size=2)+ geom_line()
```

I am not good with R, so I'm sure the answer is obvious...but I can't figure it out.  Thank you!!!

Comment: What's the range of the y-axis?

Comment: My guess would be to take the `fill = "gray"` outside of the `aes()` call.

Comment: That definitely seemed to have helped.  It's still looking more line a line plot than a ribbon, but it is thicker.

Comment: The range on the y-axis is from 10 to 25. Its a beast. I just tried temp.data$time<-as.numeric(temp.data$time), and that seemed to help too.  From what I understand, that tells R to treat my data as continuous instead of discrete.

Comment: The y-axis range might just be too big to be able to see the ribbons. The ribbons will be 0.1 units thick but you have a range of 15 units in your chart. Have you thought about using `geom_smooth` instead? See the examples [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_smooth.html).

Comment: Darn, but good to know!  I did try using geom_smooth a little bit.  From what I recall it was producing some strange patterns from my data, but I will definitely try it again and more thoroughly.  Thank you!